# Importing css automatically in a Javascript module

Tags: webpack, css-loader, javascript-import

I have written a javascript module which has custom css which is required for the app to function correctly.

This module is built with webpack with css-loader, and the compiled css appears as `dist/mymodule.css`.

The module can then be used as follows:

```
import * as mymodule from 'mymodule'
```

However to get the styling we also need to explicitly import the compiled css.

```
import 'mymodule/dist/mymodule.css'
```

Is there a way to have the css imported automatically as part of importing the module, rather than having to explicitly add it?

Comment: Webpack doesn't do what you describe out-of-the-box. What loaders are you using?

Comment: Sorry yes, this is with css-loader - the module is for use with Vue projects.